# UILabel multiline truncate middle as a whole string not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, line-breaks, truncation

I am using a `UILabel` which is of 2 lines.
I want to make it like

`"Had the best experience ever! 
She is very gener... – Mary"` truncating middle portion but I am unable to achieve the same result.

Also consider that `label` must be of 2 line and name at the end must appear.
My code for `label` for initialisation is as follow

```
    self.labelMessage = [[VTUIKit labelSecondary] addToSuperview:self];
    self.labelMessage.numberOfLines = 2;
    self.labelMessage.font = kVTFontSecondaryVeryTiny;
    self.labelMessage.textColor = kVTColorGrey300;
    self.labelMessage.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
    self.labelMessage.f_width = [VTReviewDisplayCell cellSize].width - 16;
```

And for setting `label` text

```
    NSString *reviewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", self.model.message, self.model.customer_user.first_name];
    self.labelMessage.text = reviewString;
```

I dont understand why its not working properly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,100, 250, 60)];
    contentLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    contentLabel.text = @"Had the best experience ever! She is very generally uwuq wuqe iwqwq – Mary";
    contentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
    [self.view addSubview:contentLabel];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I am adding the label to view first and setting its text by `NSString *reviewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", self.model.message, self.model.customer_user.first_name];
    
self.labelMessage.text = reviewString;`


Will that make any difference?

Comment: what is your screen size, label width and height?

Comment: I am setting the height to 60 as you suggested and width is 151 fixed for every screen size and I am supporting all iphone screens.